# How to Detect if WebView is showing a specific Website on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, detect

I am new in iOS development and  trying to make a button called `backhome` which is only visible when the user tap on the changes the native Website I set in the loadRequest.

Now my question: Is there any way to detect if the user leaves the website I set for e.g in a  if statement?

Answer (score 0):

Set a delegate for your "`UIWebView`" object and then write a method to respond to:

[webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a)

The request parameter in that call has [a URL](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLRequest/URL)  and from there, you can tell if the user has left your default website.

Comment: Dautemann Hi, I am new in ios development can you provide me some code?

Comment: it's been a few days, did you figure this out or do you still need a bit of coding direction?

Comment: Thank's for your help but the problem is gone (I dont use this) but you can answer my question if you like but I personaly dont need it anymore.